# PHP Get JSON Values Issue

Tags: php, json

I'm receiving some JSON POST data from a Webhook into my server. I can get the JSON data as follows:

```
$orderJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

which returns this JSON:

```
{
  "order": {
"billing_address": {
  "address_1": "76 Pacific Drive", 
  "address_2": "", 
  "city": "Bondi", 
  "company": "Hanson Media", 
  "country": "AU", 
  "email": "testing@gmail.com", 
  "first_name": "Hansel", 
  "last_name": "Gretten", 
  "phone": "212 554 7855", 
  "postcode": "2026", 
  "state": "NSW"
}, 
"cart_tax": "3.60", 
"completed_at": "2016-12-19T11:07:15Z", 
"coupon_lines": [], 
"created_at": "2016-12-19T11:07:15Z", 
"currency": "AUD", 
"customer": {
  "billing_address": {
    "address_1": "76 Pacific Drive", 
    "address_2": "", 
    "city": "Bondi", 
    "company": "Hanson Media", 
    "country": "AU", 
    "email": "testing@gmail.com", 
    "first_name": "Hansel", 
    "last_name": "Gretten", 
    "phone": "212 554 7855", 
    "postcode": "2026", 
    "state": "NSW"
  }, 
  "email": "testing@gmail.com", 
  "first_name": "Hansel", 
  "id": 0, 
  "last_name": "Gretten", 
  "shipping_address": {
    "address_1": "76 Pacific Drive", 
    "address_2": "", 
    "city": "Bondi", 
    "company": "Hanson Media", 
    "country": "AU", 
    "first_name": "Hansel", 
    "last_name": "Gretten", 
    "postcode": "2026", 
    "state": "NSW"
  }
}, 
"fee_lines": [], 
"id": 3304, 
"is_vat_exempt": false, 
"line_items": [
  {
    "id": 113, 
    "meta": [], 
    "name": "Happy Ninja", 
    "price": "18.00", 
    "product_id": 37, 
    "quantity": 2, 
    "sku": "", 
    "subtotal": "36.00", 
    "subtotal_tax": "3.60", 
    "tax_class": null, 
    "total": "36.00", 
    "total_tax": "3.60"
  }, 
  {
    "id": 114, 
    "meta": [], 
    "name": "Water Bottles", 
    "price": "20.50", 
    "product_id": 3291, 
    "quantity": 1, 
    "sku": "PD885536", 
    "subtotal": "20.50", 
    "subtotal_tax": "0.00", 
    "tax_class": "standard", 
    "total": "20.50", 
    "total_tax": "0.00"
  }
], 
"note": "Call to arrange delivery time", 
"order_key": "wc_order_5857bf639d951", 
"order_number": 3304, 
"payment_details": {
  "method_id": "eway", 
  "method_title": "Credit Card", 
  "paid": false
}, 
"shipping_address": {
  "address_1": "76 Pacific Drive", 
  "address_2": "", 
  "city": "Bondi", 
  "company": "Hanson Media", 
  "country": "AU", 
  "first_name": "Hansel", 
  "last_name": "Gretten", 
  "postcode": "2026", 
  "state": "NSW"
}, 
"shipping_lines": [
  {
    "id": 115, 
    "method_id": "local_pickup:1", 
    "method_title": "Local Pickup", 
    "total": "0.00"
  }
], 
"shipping_methods": "Local Pickup", 
"shipping_tax": "0.00", 
"status": "pending", 
"subtotal": "56.50", 
"tax_lines": [
  {
    "code": "AU-GST-1", 
    "compound": false, 
    "id": 116, 
    "rate_id": "1", 
    "title": "GST", 
    "total": "3.60"
  }
], 
"total": "60.10", 
"total_discount": "0.00", 
"total_line_items_quantity": 3, 
"total_shipping": "0.00", 
"total_tax": "3.60", 
"updated_at": "2016-12-19T11:07:15Z", 
"view_order_url": "https://mywebsite.com/my-account/view-order/3304"
  }
}
```

I now need to get individual elements from the JSON, e.g. I would like to get the id value (3304). I've tried:

```
$orderID = $orderJSON->id;
```

and

```
 $orderID = $orderJSON[id];
```

but this just generates errors like 'Trying to get property of non-object'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `json_decode()` function to translate your JSON file into a PHP readable data.

```
<?php
$json = json_decode($orderJSON);
```

Once you get your JSON file decoded, you can use the function `print_r()` to print a nice representation of your datas.

```
<?php
print_r($orderJSON);
```

This can help you identify how the file is formed and thus determine all the dimensions you need to display the wanted value.

[JSON to nice](http://phpio.net/s/24ri)

Now, if you look closely, you'll see that in order to print your ID, you need to pass through the order dimension.

So you may want to use the syntax `$json->order->id` to target the wanted ID.

```
<?php
echo $json->order->id;
```

[Display the ID from JSON](http://phpio.net/s/24ro)

[PHP : JSON](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.json.php).

[PHP : print_r()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php).

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) first as I can't see this in your question.
2. `id` is under `order` parent so you need to do sonething like `$orderJSON->order->id`
3. You must also check decoded `$orderJSON` is not empty

Example

```
$orderJSON = json_decode($orderJSON);
if (empty($orderJSON)) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Malformed json');
}
$orderID = $orderJSON->order->id;
```

Comment: `json_decode` returns `null` when the argument is malformed. It is advisable to check if `$orderJSON` is not empty, otherwise it would be the same 'Trying to get property of non-object'.

Comment: @AlexBlex thanks. I have updated my answer

Comment: Sorry man, it is other way round. It's actually a good example why reusing variable name is not the best practice. Hope you don't mind I edited your answer.

Comment: @AlexBlex sure no problem.

Comment: The ``empty()`` function is not what guarantee you get a well formed JSON file. It's the ``json_last_error()``.

Comment: @Gradiuss It is sufficient to guarantee the result is an object.